# Unable to clear or set blank image in imageview in android

Tags: android, imageview

```
if(bigimageS.length()==0){              

     show_image.setImageBitmap(null);   

}else{                  

  show_image.setImageBitmap(decodeImage(bigimageS));                
}

****************
    public static Bitmap decodeImage(String arrayList_image) {

        BufferedInputStream bis;
        URL aURL;
        try{        

            aURL = new URL(arrayList_image);
            URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);

            bis.close();            
            is.close();         
            return bm;          

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

this is my code and i want to clear imageview.my problem is i am getting  the image in bigimages String.i am adding the imageurl from w/s.in string bigimages.when i click on next btn after once image set then old image is not clear.so plz help i put condition but not working.plz help.

I am using the decodeimage for decode the image so is it any way to clear if there is no url in string..help me plz not solve yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got the solution..i have simply set the blank like this bigimageS="";
before getdata(); method..

Answer (score 4):

create a blank /transparent png image from photoshop , and apply as your image background.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the length of the url . If it is 0 then you have to set null to imageviwe.

Please try this.

```
if(imageneel.get(i).length() == 0)
{            
    show_image.setImageBitmap(null);
}
```

Comment: if(imageneel.size()==0){   
//show_image.setImageResource(0);
show_image.setImageBitmap(null); 
    
}else{
  show_image.setImageBitmap(decodeImage(imageneel.get(i)));
} also try but not woeking.

Answer (score 0):

try this one code

```
for (int i = 0; i < imageneel.size(); i++) {
    if(imageneel.get(i).trim().length() == 0){            
       show_image.setImageBitmap(null);
    }else{
       show_image.setImageBitmap(decodeImage(imageneel.get(i)));                
    }
}
```

Comment: hey guy chirag has already say about that but not working and i also tested that

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Pranav, but i think you can also access inbuild resources of Android itself.

Try:

```
imgView.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple as passing a 0 as the resource

```
show_image.SetImageResource(0);
```